# Javascript Arrays just not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Edited to include more of the code and new information.

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" BorderWidth="2px" CellSpacing="2" GridLines="Both" Width="465px">
    <asp:TableRow ID="labelRow0" runat="server">
        <asp:TableCell runat="server">Name</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell runat="server">Address</asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow ID="inputRow0" runat="server">
        <asp:TableCell ID="inputName" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell ID="inputAddress" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow ID="labelRow1" runat="server">
        <asp:TableCell runat="server">Favourite Colour</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell runat="server">Favourite Number</asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow ID="inputRow1" runat="server">
        <asp:TableCell ID="inputColour" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell ID="inputNumber" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
<asp:Button ID="buttonScramble" runat="server" Text="Scramble Info" onClientClick="return buttonScramble()" />
</div>

<script>
function buttonScramble() {
    var name = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
    var address = document.getElementById("TextBox2").value;
    var colour = document.getElementById("TextBox3").value;
    var number = document.getElementById("TextBox4").value;
    alert(name, address, colour, number);

    var arr = [name, address, colour, number];
    alert(arr[0]);
    //alert(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
    arr.shuffle(arr);
    alert(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
    document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = arr[0];
    document.getElementById("TextBox2").value = arr[1];
    document.getElementById("TextBox3").value = arr[2];
    document.getElementById("TextBox4").value = arr[3];
    }
```

The "alert(arr[0]);" line of code never triggers. Having checked the values of the name, address, etc.. variables, they aren't being assigned properly. Which would explain why the array isn't being assigned properly either.

Comment: if `document.getElementById("TextBox1")` doesn't exist then `document.getElementById("TextBox1").value` will create an error and alert will not run.

Comment: Are you sure all of the TextBox? IDs are present?

Comment: Try wrapping this block within try catch and see the error...

Comment: Are you calling this function somewhere?  Also you are missing the closing brace..

Comment: It's definitely being called, as any alerts placed above the array are being called. I'm going to check the textBox values, there isn't any reason I can think of that they'd be broken, but I've had weirder things happen.

Comment: Right, that helps narrow it down, the textbox values aren't being assigned.

Comment: where is the function closing brace.

Comment: Updated with all of the code except the shuffle function, which isn't being reached at all so it can't be anything in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Web Forms WebControls are notorious for the `<asp: ID=""` attribute not matching up with what is expected to be rendered because ASP.NET will rewrite the `id=""` attributes to be unique on a page (this is necessary because the client-side `id` must be unique in HTML, but a single WebControl with its own `ID=""` property could be repeated many times if rendered inside a `<asp:Repeater` or re-used UserControl.

Look at your browser's JavaScript console and JavaScript debugger - you'll probably be seeing something like "unable to access property `value` of null or undefined" because `getElementById` is returning null.

Change your JavaScript / ASP.NET to this:

```
var textBox1Id = "<%= this.TextBox1.ClientID ";
var textBox1   = document.getElementById( textBox1Id );
```

I bet that it will be rendered as something like this:

```
var textBox1Id = "__ctrl0_form0_foo_bar_textBox1";
```

Another option is to use the `ClientIDMode` property set to `Static` ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 )

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textBox1" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

...but this means setting that property on every control on your page.

Comment: Would adding a Client ID tag of some kind fix it, I remember seeing something of the sort around on the net.

Comment: @SpaceOstrich I have revised my answer to mention `ClientIDMode`.

Comment: Client mode solved it, I didn't have enough controls on the form that it was anything but trivial to make the change, and I didn't need to switch to input type Text, which could potentially cause issues in other programs with the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can wrap the values into object like this

but make sure all of you values from dom not undefined or null.

```
var arr = [{value:name}, {value:address}, {value:colour}, {value:number}]; 
console.log(arr[0]["value"]);
```

and this one

```
<button ID="buttonScramble" onClick="buttonScramble()">Scramble Info</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

take a JavaScript Object Literal, I assume your code is nicely to Xhtml rendered and delivered to
client side, the ids TextBox1, TextBox2 are assigned to input/form elements.

example:

```
function exec() {
  var name = 'answer';

  var object_literal = {
      name: document.getElementById('TextBox1').value, 
      street: document.getElementById('TextBox2').value,
      answer: name
  };
  alert(object_literal.name);
  alert(object_literal.street);
  alert(object_literal.answer);
}

exec();
```